# Why docker stack deploy can't find local image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-registry

This works fine sometimes, but sometimes docker swarm is unable to get docker image. Which has been build locally, What can be the issue here? I used the `--with-registery-auth` which has also not worked.

Please find below screenshot, which clearly states my local images are available.

[image: ScreenShot]

below is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_USER: reddituser
      MONGO_PASS: redditpass
      MONGO_DB: reddit-demo
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - reddit
    volumes:
      - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js
      - mongodb:/data/mongodb
  redisdb:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - redis:/data/
    ports:
      - "6379"
    networks:
      - reddit
  app:
    image: hapi-backend
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      MONGO_HOST: mongodb
      MONGO_PORT: "27017"
      MONGO_DB: reddit-demo
      MONGO_USER: reddituser
      MONGO_PASS: redditpass
      REDIS_HOST: redisdb
      REDIS_PORT: "6379"
    networks:
      - reddit
  micro:
    image: beequeue-micro
    environment:
      MONGO_HOST: mongodb
      MONGO_PORT: "27017"
      MONGO_DB: reddit-demo
      MONGO_USER: reddituser
      MONGO_PASS: redditpass
      REDIS_HOST: redisdb
      REDIS_PORT: "6379"
    networks:
      - reddit
volumes:
  mongodb:
  redis:
networks:
  reddit:
```

Comment: did you set registry as a service on your swarm?

Comment: No I didn't, then also it should be working without a registry also??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using registry on localhost:

So take a look at : https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/#set-up-a-docker-registry

1. Start the registry as a service on your swarm
2. Check its status with `docker service ls`
3. Check that it’s working with `curl`

Comment: Okay, But why does it work sometimes, without the registry?

Comment: perhaps it can be used the image on docker hub which is public in the internet

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem comes because you already had the stack deployed.

Usually, once you have the stack already running, the `docker stack deploy` command works, but sometimes it can't locate the appropriate image as you said.

The way I found to solve this and the one I think is the correct way is to use the command `docker service update` instead. In this command, there is the option `--force` too, which helps if docker doesn't detect changes.

Then, for your case, I would run:

```
docker service update --force reddit-demo_app
docker service update --force reddit-demo_micro
```

Then you would force updating both services.
There is also the possibility to state which image tag you want to use for the update with `--image` argument. Refer to:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_update/